# What's the meaning of "Te la bañaste" expression?

Tags: méxico, coloquialismos

- What's the meaning of the popular mexican expression "**Te (la) bañaste**", "**Se (la) bañó**"?.
- What's the origin?

Examples:

1.

> A: El profesor de matemáticas nos encargó, el día de hoy, resolver
>   cien problemas algebraicos para mañana.
>
> B: ¡Ah se la bañó! Son muchos.

2.

> A: Olvidé que ayer era el cumpleaños de mi mamá.
>
> B: Te la bañaste.
>   ¿Cómo se te pudo olvidar algo así?

3.

> A: Estabamos caminando a lado de la alberca y aventé a mi hermano a
>   ella.
>
> B: Te bañaste. Qué malo eres.

Comment: +1 First time I hear the term. Question: On the first example, should it be `¡Ah, se la baño!` or `¡Ah, se la bañó!` (past)?

Comment: I had never heard it either

Comment: 1) He's swamped us. 2) You blew it. 3) You got drenched. I don't see anything vulgar in any of these, in fact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the context where I live this expression is used to denote a type some type of excess.

> A: El profesor de matemáticas nos encargó, el día de hoy, resolver
>   cien problemas algebraicos para mañana.
>
> B: ¡Ah se la bañó! Son muchos.

In the example above it means that the professor let his students a lot of work, I don't think you can translate (even in slang) to English, in order to denote a similar meaning you would use expressions such as:

> I can't believe it.
>   Oh my God!

Comment: +1 In Spain we would say "pasarse" instead of bañarse as "Ah, ¡cómo se pasa!" or "¡ah, se ha pasado cien pueblos!" Though "dar un baño a alguien" means to beat somebody without problems.

Comment: left or gave his students a lot of work. Not let.

Answer (score 4):

I think you know the meaning now. But the origin turns out being, to me, an rhythmic euphemism to for the most common and vulgar expression *te la mamaste*, which has the same meaning. *Te la mamaste* and *te la bañaste* have the same syllable at the end, same rhythmic, same vowels. If you hear a twangy version of both expressions, you cannot tell which is which.

Another example illustrating this phenomenon would be

> ¡Pepe, *no manches*, otra vez llegaste borracho!

The "no manches" stands actually for a "no mames", which I think you are familiar with.

Comment: bañar and mamar seem very different to me.

Answer (score 3):

It is used to denote excess or exaggeration. Here is how I would translate it:

> - A: El profesor de matemáticas nos encargó, el día de hoy, resolver cien problemas algebraicos para mañana.
> - B: ¡Ah se la bañó! Son muchos.
> - A: The math teacher gave us, just today, 100 algebra problems to solve by tomorrow.
> - B: Wow, he/she swamped you. That's a lot.
> - A: Olvidé que ayer era el cumpleaños de mi mamá.
> - B: Te la bañaste. ¿Cómo se te pudo olvidar algo así?
> - A: I forgot that yesterday was my Mom's birthday.
> - B: You really blew it. How could you forget something like that?
> - A: Estabamos caminando a lado de la alberca y aventé a mi hermano a ella.
> - B: Te bañaste. Qué malo eres.
> - A: We were walking a long the edge of the pool and I shoved my brother in.
> - B: You went to far. You're terrible.

So, while there is not a single expression in English that covers all the ways that it is used in Mexico, you can translate it using any number of regional colloquial phrases that express excess. The logic of the phrase is like the English phrase of bathing your food with a sauce. Think of the action of submersing something in a tub of water, it was more than what was needed to clean it. Please note that in most of the other Spanish-speaking countries of the Americas, it is either not used or it only expresses negative excess.

Answer (score 2):

Can be used in this ways:

a ) In confidence to make joke regarding that you recently washed your genitals. Ex.
In case a person arrives and it is very evident that took a shower soon before.
Te la bañaste. - You recently washed yours.

b )  With amazement and/or admiration when people do difficult stuff. Ex.
Te la bañaste con la presentación. - Awesome report!.
Some synonymous for this lastone:

- Te la rajaste.
- Te la rifaste.
- Te la aventaste buena.
- Te la mamaste (This has multiple meanings).